# What kind of concrete mixer for a 20 cubic foot project?

Tags: concrete, masonry

I have a small concrete job that requires about 15-20 cubic feet of concrete, less than a yard. It is a wall repair that is about 3 feet above grade and has an excavation in front of it. Furthermore, an existing house and sill is above the wall, so the concrete cannot be poured in with a sluice, it will need to be pumped in.

Access to the site is limited. We can get things like small tractors and backhoe-sized equipment in there, but we cannot get a big mixer truck to the site, so the equipment needs to be tractor-sized, or towable by a tractor.

We do have electricity including 220V.

What are the recommended options for the type of equipment we should buy or rent for this job?

Comment: Think some cement companies have small tow mixers you can pickup.  They are for jobs too small for the big trucks, but kind of big for small home mixers.

Answer (score 1):

- Hand mix in a wheelbarrow
- Portable, electric powered mixer like this:

  [image: Portable, electric powered mixer]
- Towable, electric or gas powered mixer like this:

  [image: Towable, electric or gas powered mixer]

Or any similar mixer that's small enough to maneuver into your work space. Of course, you could order a truck, dispense it into a wheelbarrow at the curb and wheelbarrow it back to the work site.

<sup>Images from UnitedRentals, the first place I found in a search that had nice images I could use, no recommendation implied or intended.</sup>